# jQuery 2 column flexible using buttons

Tags: jquery, css, layout

See this fiddle for where i am stuck:
http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/hfLm3n9z/1/

I want the buttons to do the collapse, not the DIVs but I can't figure out how to cause the trigger to be them instead of the DIVs. I realize the All is not necessary but from a typical user standpoint, it will lead to less confusion in the long run.

I tried creating three scripts using the name fields for where it currently says 'div' in the JS but that stopped all function of the expand and collapse.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

HTML

```
<div style="height:10px !important;" class="selections">
<input type="button" name="ButtonLeft" value="&#60;&#60;">
<input type="button" name="ButtonAll" value="All">
<input type="button" name="ButtonRight" value="&#62;&#62;"></div>
<div class='left results'></div>
<div class='right results'></div>
```

CSS

```
* { margin: 0; }
div.results { min-height: 10em; transition: linear 0.5s; }
div.selections { min-height: 3em; }
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  background: crimson;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.expanded { width: 100%; }
.collapsed { width: 0%; }
```

JS

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded')
    .siblings().toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.lexpand').click(function(){
     $(".results").removeClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
    $(".right").toggleClass('expanded');
    $(".left").toggleClass('collapsed');
});
$('.rexpand').click(function(){ 
    $(".results").removeClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
    $(".left").toggleClass('expanded');
    $(".right").toggleClass('collapsed');
});
$('#all').click(function(){
  $(".results").removeClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
    
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; }
div.results { min-height: 10em; transition: linear 0.5s; }
div.selections { min-height: 3em; }
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  background: crimson;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.expanded { width: 100%; }
.collapsed { width: 0%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:10px !important;" class="selections"><input type="button" name="Left" class="lexpand" value="<<"><input type="button" id="all" name="All" value="All"><input type="button" name="Right" class="rexpand" value=">>"></div>
<div class='left results'></div>
<div class='right results'></div>
```

Comment: So close Tushar! The only thing it still need is for one of them to always be on screen.

For instance, click the left button then the right button. Now there is nothing on the page which should not be. I'd like to always have something there.

Comment: @user3067507 On which event ...please specify

Comment: Sorry hit the enter key thinging I would get a line break but it posted. lol

Comment: Think of it like a real estate site with left column being listings and the right being a map with pins. A user might want to see just listings or just the map or both. Perhaps my approach is wrong in the initial setup of the idea.

Comment: I got the All button to do what I wanted by adding a css class that set both to 49%. I just can't figure out how the other bit would work. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/hfLm3n9z/11/

Comment: @user3067507 check now

Comment: So what you did there was to add an additional command to remove all classes first and then apply the one to show or hide it. I think that was where I was getting confused. Thanks again, this has really helped my knowledge as well.

Comment: So one small oddity in Chrome. When you extend the left panel to full size it drops down for some reason. I tried adjusting the percentage to see if that would solve it but it is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
$("input[name='Left']").click(function(){
    $('div.left').toggleClass('expanded')
    .siblings().toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$("input[name='Right']").click(function(){
    $('div.Right').toggleClass('expanded')
    .siblings().toggleClass('collapsed');
});


$("input[name='All']").click(function(){
    $('div.Right').toggleClass('expanded').siblings().toggleClass('collapsed');
    $('div.Left').toggleClass('expanded').siblings().toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

;)